# Notation for " is not typed "

Tags: notation, type-theory

Is there a notation for "$x$ is not typed $y$"? The context is

> $x : z \:\: \vdash \:\: x$ is not typed $y$,

with $z$ and $y$ suitably defined. The obvious but awkward (and even ambiguous) thing I thought about is

> $x : z \:\: \vdash \:\: ¬$t$(x, y)$,

where t is a predicate "is typed". The next-to-obvious thing is

> $x : z \:\: \vdash \:\: x$ <s>:</s> $y$,

which is obviously ad hoc and in this case just doesn't work (minimally, I'd need a diagonal strikeout)

I would eventually use the notation in Latex, but this isn't a Latex question, as it's about a notation (and not about how to get a diagonal strikeout in Latex, which I know [how to do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4465/put-a-slash-through-a-word/4468#4468))